# Parameter-dependent behaviour in custom command involving \begin{document}...\end{document}

Tags: macros

Why does `mycommandA` work but not `mycommandB`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mycommandA}{
    \begin{document}
        A
    \end{document}
}

\newcommand{\mycommandB}[1][]{
    \begin{document}
        B
    \end{document}
}

% \mycommandA % works
% \mycommandB % doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `\mycommandB` is the last token in the file, TeX stops for input, because it's looking for something in order to decide whether an optional argument follows.

Indeed, with

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mycommandA}{
    \begin{document}
        A
    \end{document}
}

\newcommand{\mycommandB}[1][]{
    \begin{document}
        B
    \end{document}
}

% \mycommandA % works
 \mycommandB % doesn't work
```

the terminal shows `*` and waits for user input. Hitting the return key ends the run. However, if you run `pdflatex` with the `-interaction=nonstopmode` flag, you get

```
! Emergency stop.
<*> mjc

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

because in this mode, user input cannot be obtained.

On the other hand, if I add anything after `\mycommandB` (a blank line, for instance), the run is successful also in `nonstopmode`.